# IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin doesn't find errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've just tried IntelliJ IDEA 12 with the Scala plugin, but it doesn't find and highlight errors in my code. I can for example write arbitrary code in a method and it looks like everything is fine. Is IDEA not able to do this? Or do I have to configure something special?

Comment: I have IDEA 12 with the Scala plug-in running just fine. Can you look at your plug-ins and see if it is enabled? Which version are you using? Have you enabled Type-aware highlighting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IDEA's Scala plug-in is not equivalent to the compiler in type-checking your source code, but it does pretty well. The one thing you'll want to do (unless, perhaps, your hardware is not fairly current and high-performance) is turn on "Type-Aware Highlighting."

If you look in the lower-right-hand corner of the IDEA window (when you're editing a project with Scala enabled) you'll see one of two icons, both of which take the form of a square-bracketed bit of text. That text is either blank on a yellow background or the letter `T` on a green background. Clicking it toggles between those two states. When the green `T` is displayed, Type-Aware highlighting is on.

Give that a try.

Comment: Even with type-aware hilighting on, IDEA will occasionally (rarely actually) fail to catch some errors, and more commonly will also red-line perfectly good code.  This is due to the plugin using its own typechecker rather than the compiler.  Just a consequence of the tooling for scala still not being quite as polished.  

Installing the SBT plugin and running ~compile or ~test in that window tends to be a big help.

Comment: @ChuckAdams: Indeed. That's what I said, albeit less precisely than I should have.

Comment: The false positives for Scala type-aware tends to be on implicits, so I just ignore if it looks implicit related.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. Some [pictures and details](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/03/02/type-aware-highlighting/) in the IntelliJ Scala blog.

Comment: Furthermore, even when the type-aware highlighting is on, IntelliJ can be in "power saving" mode. You can toggle that via the [little face icon](http://www.jetbrains.com/img/webhelp/hector.png). This is notable because it's particularly hard to find... You can't find it through the standard settings dialog... More information about "power save" mode exists in [IntelliJ's status-bar documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/status-bar.html).

Comment: I know that "thank you" comments are not encouraged on SO, but this is the time when I can't follow the rules. You saved me a great amount of headache, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Simply updating the plugin version could fix the problem. Old or install/initial plugins may not contain relevant support.

Determining Scala plugin version in Settings:
[image: Determining Scala plugin version in Settings]