# Scala compilation on the fly in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with scala plugin. It looks like it's impossible to configure showing compilation errors on the fly. 
For example when you are writing code in java you can see compilation errors right after you edited the file.
How can I tune this feature for scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities to automatically show errors in Intellij IDEA:

#### Code Highlighting

The majority of errors will be highlighted with a curvy red line and an error mark on the right side.

This can be configured in the settings. You can find the relevant options under `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Color & Fonts` -> `General`, in the right list select `Error`, now you can change the appearance of the error highlighting or en/disable it.

As mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462923/3973371 it is also possible that the type aware highlighting is disabled. To enable it click on the yellow square, it should contain `[_]`, in the lower right corner. If the type awareness is enabled it should be green and contain `[T]`.

#### Auto make

If you want all errors listed you can activate `Make project automatically` in the settings. It is located at `Settings` -> `Compiler`.

This will show all errors in the Problems section immediately after an edit.